# Regex in Classic ASP VB

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I just want to match the first instance, could anyone let me know how you would go about doing this?

```
'RegEx to get Image
Dim re, matches, Img
Set re = new RegExp     ' creates the RegExp object
re.IgnoreCase = true
re.Global = true
re.Pattern = "<img.*(.|\n)*?/>"
Set Matches  = re.Execute(string)
Img = ""

For each Item in Matches
   Img = Item.Value
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Global` property should be `false`, rather than `true`.

The property is described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdte5kwf(v=VS.85).aspx.