# Regex in ASP extraction

Tags: regex, asp-classic

Ok, I come from a PHP background, but I need to extract something from a URL using classic ASP.

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/page1/link.asp';
```

The ASP code will strip out http:// or http:// www and just extract
domain.com (page1) (link.asp)

In PHP, you can use the preg_match function, but how would a ASP version work?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519144/regex-in-classic-asp-vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work (untested):

```
Dim regEx, strFinal

Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "^https?://(www\.)?";
regEx.IgnoreCase = True

strFinal = regEx.Replace("http://domain.com/page1/link.asp", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work. (Tested)

```
Dim regEx, strFinal

Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "^https?://(www\.)?"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True

strFinal = regEx.Replace("http://www.domain.com/page1/link.asp", "")
Response.Write strFinal
```